# I want to generate a new page where someone can comment something

Tags: php

I want to generate a new page where someone can comment and see the post they clicked on, I currently have my database being looped and echoed onto the screen, they are clickable i'm just not sure how to make it so in generates its own page with the post they clicked on.

```
else{
        $postquery = "SELECT `users`.`username`,`posts`.`text`,`posts`.`date`,`posts`.`title` FROM `users` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `users`.`user_id` = `posts`.`user_id` ORDER BY `posts`.`post_id` DESC";
        $post = mysqli_query($dbc,$postquery);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($post) > 0) {
            foreach($post as $row) {
?>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="post.html">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                        <!-- TITLE OF POST -->
                           <?php echo $row["title"];?>
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        <!-- CONTENT OF POST -->
                           <?php echo $row['text']; ?>
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <?php echo $row['username'];?></a><?php echo " On " . $row['date'];?></p>
                </div>
<?php           
            }   
        }
    }
```

This will output something like the following:
Title: Post
Content: Blablalala
Posted by: user On 2016-04-02

And what i want to do is make it so i can click the "Title" as a hyperlink and get directed to a different page where i see just that post and are able to comment on it. I heard of using "GET" as a method but currently i'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `<a href=""></a>` and link to the other page.

```
<h2 class="post-title">
       <!-- TITLE OF POST -->
       <a href="anotherpage.php?title=<?php echo $row["title"];?>">
          <?php echo $row["title"];?>
       </a>
 </h2>
```

But the better option is to use the post_id for linking to the post detail:

```
<h2 class="post-title">
       <!-- TITLE OF POST -->
       <a href="anotherpage.php?id=<?php echo $row["post_id"];?>">
          <?php echo $row["title"];?>
       </a>
 </h2>
```

And from anotherpage.php you get it by id and make the query:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$singlepost = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE post_id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $singlepost);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then your can normally output like this:

```
echo $row['title'];
echo $row['text']
echo $row['username'];
```

And put your comment like below:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Have your say</label>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="5" name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment">
</form>
```

You can check whether there is comment and update the same:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $comment = isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment']:'';
      $id = $_POST['id];
      if(empty($comment)){
        $error = "Comment field is blank";
      }else{
         mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO comment (comment, post_id)
                             VALUES ('$comment', '$id')");
       }
     }
```

Check whther there is error while posting comment.

```
 if(!empty($error)){
    echo $error;
   }
```